# Reaction of Iron(III) with hydroxide ion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, colloids

**The observations:**

1) Treatment of 1 mL of 0.05 M $\ce{Fe(NH4)SO4}$ solution with excess 1 M $\ce{NaOH}$ results in the formation of a rust-colored red-brown iron-based solution with many suspended particles in the solution. These particles match the description of $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$. This is the vial on the right in the picture.

2) Treatment of 1 mL of 0.05 M $\ce{Fe(NH4)SO4}$ solution with excess 6 M $\ce{NaOH}$ results in the formation of a clear but colored solution with no suspended particles in the solution or any sort of precipitate. The yellow-brown colored solution matches the description $\ce{Fe(OH2)4(OH)2+}$. This is the vial on the left.

[image]

Why is it that treatment with *more concentrated* base results only two apparent deprotonations rather than three?

**More observations (after about 10 minutes):**

1) The 1 mL of 0.05 M $\ce{Fe(NH4)SO4}$ solution treated with excess 6 M $\ce{NaOH}$ has developed suspended particles. This is the vial on the left.

2) The 1 mL of 0.05 M $\ce{Fe(NH4)SO4}$ solution treated with excess 1 M $\ce{NaOH}$ has started to become clear (the suspended particles are disappearing). It seems like much of the particles have settled on the bottom. This is the vial on the right.

[image]

It seems that the 6 M $\ce{NaOH}$ is eventually "getting the job done" by going through with the third deprotonation of $\ce{Fe(OH2)6^{3+}}$. I don't think that the 1 M $\ce{NaOH}$ is deprotonating $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$.

Still, why is it that treatment of iron(III) ions with concentrated base does not result in the formation of $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$ immediately but treatment with less concentrated base does?

**Even more observations:**

1) Treatment of 10 mL of 0.05 M $\ce{Fe(NH4)SO4}$ with excess 6 M NaOH results in immediate and obvious $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$ formation. This seems to support the nucleation explanation; the higher solution volume means lower concentration and lower supersaturation and therefore fewer and larger crystals of $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$ being formed.

**Possible explanations I came up with:**

1) I ran the results past a grad student and he said his best guess is that the excess $\ce{HO-}$ present stabilizes $\ce{Fe(OH2)4(OH)2+}$. He suggested a conductivity test to make sure that there are $\ce{Fe(OH2)4(OH)2+}$ ions in the clear solution. However, I did not have a conductivity meter handy.

2) A problem in the lab manual from an unrelated section notes that strongly electrolytic solutions, such as saturated $\ce{H4NCl}$ solution, can cause dispersion rather than dissolution of $\ce{Al(OH2)3(OH)3}$ in solution. A 6 M $\ce{NaOH}$ solution is strongly electrolytic, and as a result, the ions may be keeping the $\ce{Fe(OH2)3(OH)3}$ from clumping together.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't expect the reactions to yield different products but rather different particle size. The higher concentrated $\ce{NaOH}$ should hereby produce smaller particles†.

The "solution" in the left vial is probably rather a colloid of microscopically dispersed iron(III) hydroxide. It should show the [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect) if you send a beam of light through it. However, the particles will aggregate over time to form larger particles that also precipitate, as seen in the second image.

---

† Higher concentration means higher supersaturation. Higher supersaturation leads to a higher [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallization#Primary_nucleation) rate, so more and thus smaller crystals are being formed.

Comment: why would the particles start out as microscopically dispersed?

Comment: @Dissenter They always do, but kinetics of aggregation may vary.

Comment: @Mithoron - makes sense. There was a question in the lab manual that talked about strong electrolytic solutions possibly causing metal hydroxides to "disperse" instead of dissolve. 6 M NaOH is a _very_ strong electrolytic solution, and that may be keeping the metal hydroxide particles that form from clumping together.

Comment: @Dissenter Precicipate rarely 'aggregates', aging of precipitate includes dissolution of smaller particles and growth of larger ones. Obviously, strongly basic solution prevents dissolution of iron hydroxide.

Comment: @permeakra - why don't they clump together?

Comment: @aventurin what do you think about the anionic stabilization hypothesis?

Comment: It is known that colloid iron oxy-hydroxide can stabilize by adsorption of protons on the surface of the particles. They repel each other when charged. But I would expect less positive charge at higher pH. The sign of the charge can be determined experimentally by electrophoresis in a U-shaped tube. However it may be difficult to conduct with high concentrations where the particles coagulate fast and then sink to the ground.

Comment: @aventurin - by iron oxy-hydroxide do you mean FeO(OH) and related compounds?

Comment: Yes, this somehow describes the stoichiometry of the precipitate.